# linq to accept nullable value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
 var menuItems = from c in xMenuElement.Elements("GlobalNavigation").Elements("PrimaryLink")
                 where c.Element("SecondaryLink").Element("LeftMenu").Element("NavLinks").Element("LinkID").Value.Trim() == "sad1" 
                 select c;
```

Comment: And what's your question/problem?

Comment: from c in xMenuElement.Elements("GlobalNavigation").Elements("PrimaryLink")
                            where
                            c.Element("SecondaryLink").Element("LeftMenu").Element("NavLinks").Element("LinkID").Value.Trim() == "sad1" select c;

Comment: it has reprtion if multiple nodes .. so if the first node is null means its throws error..

Comment: it should accept null values also..

Comment: @ram: Edit your question and put all of this in there that you have already said in comments. Otherwise, your question will get closed soon.

Comment: @Aamir: It is closing in 5.. 4.. 3.. 2.. 1.. closed :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this technique can be repeated multiple times

```
var menuItems = from c in xMenuElement.Elements("GlobalNavigation").Elements("PrimaryLink")
                let secondaryLink = c.Element("SecondaryLink")
                where secondaryLink != null 
                   && secondaryLink.Element("LeftMenu").Element("NavLinks").Element("LinkID").Value.Trim() == "sad1"
                select c;
```

Otherwise you can create a Method:

```
var menuItems = from c in xMenuElement.Elements("GlobalNavigation").Elements("PrimaryLink")
                let linkId = GetLinkId(c)
                where linkId != null 
                select c;

string GetLinkId(XElement element)
{
    var secondaryLink = element.Element("SecondaryLink");
    if (secondaryLink == null) return null;
    var leftMenu = secondaryLink.Element("LeftMenu");
    if (leftMenu== null) return null;
    // ...
    return linkId.Value;
}
```

If you are still getting a null reference exception it might be your source that has the issue.

```
var globalNav = xMenuElement.Elements("GlobalNavigation");
if (globalNav != null)
{
    var primaryLinks = globalNav.Elements("PrimaryLink");
    if (primaryLinks != null)
    {
           var menuItems = from c in primaryLinks //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: To prevent NullRefEx you need a deeply nested query for each level of Elements

Comment: now its checking all null values. i have check whether "linkid=sad" also

Comment: Good, please mark the answer as accepted.  In the future please try to add more of a description to your question and choose edit question to provide further details based on user comments.  Otherwise your future questions will continue to get Closed :(